# Using Entity Framework data mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Code sample for controller written in c# using visual studio 2010 express-

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var _user = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();

        var profiles = from p in db.Profiles
                       where p.UserId == _user
                       select new
                       {
                           ProfileId = p.ID
                       };

        return View(profiles.ToList());
    }
```

Code from view -

```
@model List<MyProject.Models.Profile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
```

and I continualyl get this error -

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.Profile]'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are projecting to an anonymous object, just like the compiler message says. If you actually want a list of Profile objects, you should replace the select clause in your linq query with simply

```
 select p;
```

That is, assuming that db.Profiles contains your model object (of type Model.Profile)

Answer (score 3):

You should have

```
 var profiles = from p in db.Profiles
                       where p.UserId == _user
                       select p;
```

to meet your view's requirement for model.